# How to get history of Chrome's incognito mode?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-contentprovider

I am getting history of Chrome browser using **content://com.android.chrome.browser/bookmarks.** it working fine.but Now, I need to get browsing URLs of incognito mode. 
So How can I get urls or history of incognito mode.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. According to the official pages:

> If you don’t want Google Chrome to save a record of what you visit and download, you can browse the web in incognito mode.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en

This means Chrome does not save the history of the user in incognito mode.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get history of incognito mode .....

open cmd prompt and just type  C:\Users\user>`ipconfig /displaydns`